# Android, InfoWindows not follow the marker postion changes

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, infowindow, marker

I have changed the position of a marker in the map. If an InfoWindow of one marker is shown then I want that the InfoWindow should remain visibile but it should be in the new position of the marker and with the new information.
However the infowindow update the information but still remain in the old marker position.

```
 ....
 mrk.setPosition(v.getPostion());
 mrk.setSnippet(v.getSpeed() );
 //update the information                                                  
 if(mrk.isInfoWindowShown()){
   mrk.hideInfoWindow();
   mrk.showInfoWindow();
    }
```

Comment: First try to remove this marker and after updating marker info try again add this marker with updated info.

Comment: You need to set a new position for your marker.